# GCC compiler errors with “No such file or directory”

Tags: c, linux, gcc

My Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS. I have a C program copied on the desktop by the name sendRawEth.c. When I write:

```
gcc sendRawEth.c -o sendRawEth
```

The compiler complains:

```
gcc: error: sendRawEth.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

I have no idea how to solve this error.

Comment: Did you `cd` to your desktop before typing that?

Comment: cd - change directory. Invoke gcc after you get to the directory(Desktop in your case) where your .c file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please do the following.
On terminal check the present directory by 'pwd' command and then check the directory in which your programme is there and see if they are same or not. And while writing gcc yourfile it's case sensitive. Hope this helps

Comment: Why do you use the "kernel" word in your answer? It does not look appropriate

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons for such errors.

1. You said you copied your `C` programs in your desktop folder.

   - This means you may have only copied `sendRawEth.c`. file format not the executable file.
   - You should ensure you copy the `.exe` files as well.
2. You need to change the directory to the same folder that you copied your programs into.

First, check your current folder by typing `pwd`.

Then change it to your required folder with:

```
cd /outerfolder/your program folder
```

Then compile it with:

```
gcc -o programname programname.c
```

And finally execute it with:

```
./programname
```